# c# limit the text inserted in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, text, richtextbox, limit

I want to limit the text inserted in a richtextbox (`rtb`) knowing that:

1. a line can have multiple text sizes
2. the text can only be written until it reaches the rtb visible size

My idea was to calculate the text height and compare it with the `rtb` height.

Is there a way to calculate this height by line and not by char? Any other good approach would be gladly accepted.

Comment: why not use MaxLength to set the size?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: He can't use MaxLength because depending on the size of the font, MaxLength could be different.

Comment: I have found a solution.

Comment: last rtb char position+inserte char height<rtb.height